# How Do I Simulate Pressing a button on a webpage using the "requests" library in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'd like to programmatically press the "Next Week" button on the webpage
http://investing.com/economic-calendar/

and use BeautifulSoup to pull the resulting table. I am able to extract the table using BeautifulSoup but cannot seem to be able to programmatically click the "Next Week" button

By inspecting the webpage, I can see that the button which I should click is "newBtn toggleButton LightGray" and I think I should be using post commands in order to simulate this click, but the below code doesn't seem to work, although I think I am close:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import requests

uri = 'http://investing.com/economic-calendar/'
data = {'newBtn toggleButton LightGray' : 'clicked'}
page_data = requests.post(uri, data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_data.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {"id": "economicCalendarData"})
tbody = table.find('tbody')
rows = tbody.findAll('tr', {"class": "js-event-item"})
```

Here is the relevant "elements" section when I inspect the page when hovering the "Next Week" button. I think from my code, the following line is wrong but I'd like to know why and what would be the correct one:

data = {'newBtn toggleButton LightGray' : 'clicked1'}

[image]

Comment: `requests` only does basic HTTP operations such as get and post.  It does not do any javascript.  So if the button click simply triggers a post, then yes you can simulate it with requests.  But if it does any javascript processing, then you can't.

Answer (score 1):

2 possible options

1. Use 'Selenium' which means you're simulating browsing the page
2. You get the id of the link and then trigger click event from Javascript (which means you essentially have a client side)

Comment: keep at it with the answers!

Comment: Thanks, Im avoiding Selenium as I'm using a Linux server, so trying method 2. I edited my answer to include my code, is there something I'm missing in my code?

Comment: The only additional thing I see in your code is the image of the element. You need to trigger a click which as far I know means you need Javascript. I don't see that in your code